# Using $emit to call a function

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue.js and am trying to understand how `$emit` can be used. In the following code, every `input` element except for the last one works as expected.

My assumption in the last `input` element is that calling `$emit` with an event name would be the same as calling the function which has that event name, but it doesn't call that function. What is occurring with this $emit?

I've read through [Binding Native Events to Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) and that shows that it is to be used differently as I'm doing it. All this approach started from me watching a YouTube video (7 Secret Patterns...), specifically at this time https://youtu.be/7lpemgMhi0k?t=21m57s where you can see that usage on the slide.

Here is the code in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sbtmfweq/

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="test-app">
  <input v-model="text1" placeholder="edit me" @keyup.enter="submit"> {{ text1 }}
  <br><br>
  <input :value="text2" @input="inputEvent" @keyup.enter="submit"> {{ text2 }}
  <br><br>
  <input :value="text2" @input="inputEvent($event)" @keyup.enter="submit"> {{ text2 }}
  <br><br>
  <input :value="text2" @input="$emit('inputEvent', $event.target.value)"> {{ text2 }} | {{reversedText2}}
</div>

<script>

  new Vue({
    el: '#test-app',
    data: {
      text1: 'text1',
      text2: 'text2',
    },
    methods: {
      log: console.log,
      submit: function(event) {
        console.log("submit -->", event, event.target.value, '<--')
      },
      inputEvent: function(event) {
        console.log("input 2 -->", event.target.value, '<--')
        this.text2 = event.target.value
      },
    },
    watch: {
      text1: {
        handler: function(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log("input 1 -->", newValue, '<-->', oldValue, '<--')
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      reversedText2: function () {
        return this.text2.toUpperCase()
      }
    }
  })

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a simple issue. Whenever you are dispatching an event, you have to add listener to it. In $emit, the first param is actually the name of the event.

As written in docs for $emit.

> vm.$emit( eventName, […args] )

In the below code, I have added an event listener, using $on. Also I have changed the arg for $emit.

```
  <input :value="text2" @input="$emit('inputEvent', $event)"> {{ text2 }} | {{reversedText2}}

<script>

  new Vue({
    ...
    created(){
        this.$on('inputEvent', this.inputEvent);
    }
    ...
  })

</script>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why I should avoid this pattern and use one of the three methods used above the last one, or is this a perfectly fine/valid usage of `$emit`? I'm asking because it is not used in a child-parent context.

Comment: This is really what I was looking for. I like the decoupling between the $emit event name and the function to be called.

Comment: To be honest you should avoid all the four for this particular case. Vue provides 2way bindings using v-model. I believe that's the best way to do so. See I have modified your fiddle. Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/dy2rw70p/2/

Comment: That looks just like the first one with an added `:value` (to which I also had added a watch just to see if there is a way to get in-code notification of the change)

Comment: Is it "normal" to use `this.$emit` together with `this.$on` to implement a pubsub system in vue?

Comment: Sorry that :value is not needed, only v-model will work. And it's not normal to use $emit and $on unless you want to communicate with the parent component or in case of services(angular style).

Answer (score 1):

`$emit` works like this.

Say you have 2 components, `<parent>` and `<child>`, where `<child>` is inside `<parent>`'s template.

When `<child>` emits an event, it can be handled by the `<parent>` component only (unless you register a listener via `$on`, but that's unrelated to your scenario). In your code, the `$emit` call is executed within the scope of the parent component (which is the root component instantiated with `new Vue()`); that is, the parent component is the one that's emitting the event. The root component has no parent so the emit call is pointless.

> My assumption in the last `input` element is that calling `$emit` with an event name **would be the same as calling the function which has that event name**, but it doesn't call that function.

This isn't true; the name of the event has no relation to the method registered as a listener for that event in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

it's normal that `$emit` doesn't work in your case.

In fact, `$emit` is used for communication between parent and child components. Here, you are using `$emit` but you haven't defined any parent component.

Here is the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) for the custom events.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So `$emit` is not something similar to a publication into a pubsub-system, to which the functions in `methods` get subscribed to automatically? It is only meant for child-to-parent communication?